# TabContiner with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a question. Is it possible to work with AJAX Control Toolkit in razor views?
I need to use TabContainer or similar (it could be a HTML Helper)

I know I can use it in aspx but I'm using Layouts on my project... so maybe a partial view is the solution, I really don't know.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a question. Is it possible to work with AJAX Control Toolkit in razor views?

Not recommended. The AJAX Control Toolkit consists of server side controls which depend on ViewState and PostBack which are notions that no longer exist in ASP.NET MVC. So referencing the AjaxControlToolkit assembly inside an ASP.NET MVC application is like attaching a caravan on a Lamborghini.

As an alternative you might take a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which has many useful widgets [such as Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).